# how to add a shared colorkey in multi panel levelplot?

Tags: r

I'm plotting 4 raster plots and want them not a have their individual legend but a shared legend.
what I'm using right now is the following code for plotting the rasters:

```
library(raster)
color_range <- colorRampPalette(c("aliceblue", "deepskyblue3","darkblue"))
my_colors <- color_range(7)
my.at=c(seq(0,1200,by=200),Inf)
my.brks=c(seq(0,1200,by=200),Inf)
myColorkey <- list(at=my.at, labels=c("0","200","400","600","800","1000","1200","Inf"))
plot_one<-levelplot( raster_layer, col.regions=my_colors, at=my.at, colorkey=myColorkey,
                 margin=F,
                 cex.main =0.3,line = 0.5,
                 xlab = "longitude (°E) ", ylab ="latitude (°N)")
plot_one<-plot_one+  layer(panel.text(x=90, y=35, labels=paste("Mean:", 
                                                                               round(mean(getValues(raster_layer), na.rm=TRUE), 2),"mm \n"), 
                                                      col="red", cex=1.1, font=1))+
  layer(panel.text(x=90, y=35, labels=paste("\n Median:",
                                            round(median(getValues(raster_layer), na.rm=TRUE), 2),"mm"), 
                   col="green", cex=1.1, font=1))
```

This also adds the eman and median of the singular rasters. and to combine the levelplot into single plot I'm using the following:

```
  grid.arrange(plot_one, plot_two, plot_three, plot_four, ncol=2,top = textGrob("combined",gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=3)))
```

when I'm using this I get individual legend for all which seems redundant. I would prefer if i could plot the 4 without legend and have a common legend at the bottom or right. I have tried some solutions online but most of them works for ggplot and not for levelplot.

How should I modify this current snippet.
since dput of original raster is too large assume a random raster below.

```
raster_layer <- raster(matrix(runif(rows * cols, min = 50, max = 1200), nrow = 100, ncol = 100), xmn = 0, xmx = 10, ymn = 0, ymx = 10)
```

edit: there's a method to stack the rater and then plot them. However I see that the coordinates are not plotted for all individual plots. also I'm unable to add individual rasters mean and median values.

```
k<-stack( raster_layer, raster_layer, raster_layer, raster_layer)


plot_one<-levelplot(k, col.regions=my_colors, at=my.at, colorkey=myColorkey,
                    margin=F,main="plot",
                    cex.main = 0.3,line = 0.5,
                    xlab = "longitude (°E) ", ylab = "latitude (°N)")
```

Comment: What package does `levelplot` come from? Please list all `library()` calls necessary to run the code.